# View changelog of all packages to be upgraded before upgrading

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, deb

When using synaptic on my Ubuntu desktop computer i can review all changelog of all the packages to be upgraded, and unselect a package for upgrade if I want. On my desktop I usually install everything, but I like to at least review what the changes are so that I can delay the upgrade if I suspect it could cause problems with the development tools I use.

On a server (Ubuntu Server) with no x-server how can I do the same thing on the console:

- list all packages that will be updated (`apt-get --dry-run upgrade` does this along with a lot of noisy simulated install messages),
- view the changelog (if any) from last upgrade to the version it will be upgraded to.
- select which packages I want to ignore, or which I want to upgrade

I've searched a lot for this but I haven't found anything, possibly I'm not using the correct terminology; but surely this must be possible. Synaptic must get it's info from some some low-level tool I assume?

Complicated shellscripts are welcome too, if this is not already easily done with the existing tools.

Comment: I don't know offhand how to do this, however, have you read over the man pages (man apt-get) or the help switch (apt-get --help)?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking. It could be a switch that does this, but I don't see it.. Culd be the man pages uses terms I wouldn't think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `apt-listchanges` package. Then when you run `apt-get upgrade` it should give you the list of changes before you go ahead.

Comment: Seems like it's the tool I wanted. Thanks! Just have to wait for new upgrades to test it... :)

Comment: Are there any options I need to supply to the apt-get upgrade command to make it list the changes? Tried it now, and it didn't show any list...

Comment: Have a look at /etc/apt/listchanges.conf and see what "which" is set to. I think it defaults to "news". Change it to "changelogs" or "both".

Comment: Also, install apticron and set your email up in '/etc/apticron/apticron.conf'. That way you'll get regular emails with any changes.

Comment: Works nicely now, I just had to change the /etc/apt/listchanges.conf so that "which=both" and "confirm=1" to get it to list the changelog and ask to continue afterwards.